# Samsung SMT-G7401 hack

Tags: terminal, access-control, serial-console, uart

## Samsung SMT-G7401 hack

### introduction

I have an SMT-G7401_PCS01B (Horizon box) from UPC Switzerland and I would like to install debian or multimedia linux distribution on it if is it possible, if is it not possible I just take the hdd for my PC. (I have recently received the "UPC TV Box")

### Possible and not possible way

- I can get log from the UART interface with an "FTDI FT232RL" + "minicom". I have the serial console but I can't do anything.

```
POST: 0xb03
wdt: reset type = 0, reset reason = 0
POST: 0xc02
cefdk_rom_base_addr: 0x00280800
POST: 0xc1f
wdt: acboot win2 end, counter=981466
POST: 0xf02
Warning: No device found in chip select 0
Spi Flash Init Failed and disable SPI Fl
Intel(R) Consumer Electronics Firmware Development Kit (Intel(R) CEFDK)
Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
Build Time (04/17/14 19:20:25).
POST: 0xf05Loading 8051_fw from MFH...
POST: 0xf07
Set flash layout to Samsung 128MB layout
POST: 0xf18
---memory initialization for postbox communication -----
POST: 0xf19
Waiting for 5 sec for DOCSIS PLL1 ready...
DOCSIS PLL1 ready
POST: 0xfa0
SMM: Ok
POST: 0xf24
ACPI Init: finished with table region from 00011ab0 to 00018000
acpi: Created tables at 00011ab0-00018000
POST: 0xf29
HW Revision          : 12
CEFDK Version        : CE2600 build (SMP enabled)
8051 Firmware        : A0-1.2.0 build R 0x20A
8051 FW I/O Module   : 
Silicon Stepping     : B2 
Silicon SKU          : 0x037
Board Set As         : Harbor Park - MG
CPU Threads          : 2
CPU Multiplier       : 12
CPU Bus Speed        : 100 MHz
Memory Size          : 512 MB
Memory Type & Speed  : x16 DDR3-1333 (10-10-10) 
Trusted Boot         : Untrusted
Boot Mode            : eMMC-NAND (STRAPS)
Registered net controller: e1000
Init External Switch for board Type: 1
Timing data c003
Timing data c03e
ESWITCH ID 1761
1000M FD Link is ready!
Configure IP via static IP.
Mac address is    : 54:FA:3E:2F:3C:E3
Host IP address is: 192.168.192.1
Subnet Mask is    : 255.255.255.0
Gateway address is: 192.168.192.1

================================================
WARNING:
  Please make sure the board type and DOCSIS DDR offset/size are set correctly,
  otherwise DOCSIS subsystem won't boot!
  If not sure, please use "settings" shell command to show the setup menu,
  then check "Advanced Features".
================================================

Press 'Enter' within 0 seconds to disable automatic boot.
Hit a key to start the shell...
**********************************************************
***** Uboot is not upgraded --- boot kernel          *****
**********************************************************
Running auto script...
shell> load -m 0x200000 -i a -t emmc
get Active Image info success:240000, 400000, 1, 1, 3
eMMC kernel command:  root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 
Load data from emmc
Load done.
shell> bootkernel -b 0x200000 "console=ttyS0,115200 ip=static rw"
 --- bootkernel  ...
...  CEFDK -> U-Boot status STAT_USR_FIN 
 L2sw mode ---
Working Cmd: console=ttyS0,115200 ip=static rw root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 
CMD(0x48000)='console=ttyS0,115200 ip=static rw root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 '
WARNING: Ancient bootloader, some functionality may be limited!
```

- I have a JTAG interface but I don't the necessary stuff to use it. I have search for an arduino JTAG adapter but I have no found any good way.
- Two USB port are there but they are inactive. I read that they are used for diagnostic and specific utilisation.
- The final way is a mysterious plug, his name is "MPEG/ARM CONSOLE". I found nothing about it. [EDIT] I know wich pin is RX, TX and GND, from left to right (when you watch the plug): GND, TX, RX, ?, ?, ?.

I can maybe burn linux distribution directly on the HDD. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Mother board infos
[image: Mother board infos]
UART pinout
[image: UART pinout]